# unable to any confirmation or anything happening after a post

Tags: php, post

I'm using a modal in php to post data and the code is as below.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <!-- Modal content -->
   <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <form class="form-horizontal content">
         <fieldset>
            <!-- Form Name -->
            <legend>Application</legend>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Full Name">Full Name</label>  
               <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input id="Full Name" name="fName" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Email">Email</label>  
               <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input id="Email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="roleFor">Role Applying for</label>  
               <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input id="roleFor" name="roleFor" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="jobId">Job ID</label>  
               <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input id="jobId" name="jobId" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- File Button --> 
            <!--div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="uploadResume">Upload Resume</label>
               <div class="col-md-4">
                 <input id="uploadResume" name="uploadResume" class="input-file" type="file">
               </div>
               </div-->
            <!-- Textarea -->
            <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="experience">Experience</label>
               <div class="col-md-4">                     
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="experience" name="exp"></textarea>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
               <div class="col-md-4">
                  <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </fieldset>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

and my js has

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
 $(function() {
    //twitter bootstrap script
    $("button#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "sendEmail.php",
                data: $('form.content').serialize(),
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#thanks").html(msg);
                    $("#myModal").modal('hide'); 
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                }
       });
    });
});
</script>
```

and the sendEmail file is

```
<?php
$fName = $_POST['fName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$roleFor = $_POST['roleFor'];
$jobId = $_POST['jobId'];
$exp = $_POST['exp'];

if (!empty($fName) && !empty($email)) {
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbUserName = "myUser";
    $dbPassword = "myPwd";
    $dbname = "myDb";
    try {
        $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUserName, $dbPassword, $dbname);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo 'Error : ' . $ex->getMessage();
    }
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die('Connect Error(' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ')' . mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
        echo $fName . ' and ' . $email;
       
    }
} else {
    echo "Enter both Title and Desription";
    die();
}
?>
```

Here when I hit submit, my page just reloads, nothing gets echoed.

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to fix this

1. Remove the form tag or close it before set the button
2. Set type of the button to button like: `<button id="submit" type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>`

Otherwise the button will always submit the form instead of waiting for the ajax call